# How can I prove that a group acts on these sets:

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Suppose that G is a group and X is a set. An action of G on X is a map G× X → X where
$(g, x) → g \circ x$ such that both

(a) $1_G \circ x = x$ for each x ∈ X and
(b) $g \circ (h \circ x) = (gh) \circ x$ for all g, h ∈ G and x ∈ X.

> Prove that: $S_n$ acts on {1, 2, . . . , n} via application of each map. Where 
>   $S_n$ is the symetric group.

Also:

> Prove that: A group G acts on itself (as X) by left multiplication: $g \circ x = gx$

For this one I guess I solved it alright by doing:
$g \circ (h \circ x)=ghx$ and because the group operation is associative it follows that $g \circ (h \circ x)=(gh)\circ x$
This would prove (b), I would want an opinion if it's right.

> Prove:  A group G does not act on itself (as X) by right multiplication: $g \circ x = xg$

For this one I thought that $g \circ (h \circ x)=xhg$ which is not possible because xhg can't be rearanged so that is equal to $(gh)\circ x$

But again it is not concrete for me what I am saying so it might be wrong.

I know that I must prove both criteria from above, but I stuck.

Comment: Can you at least show us your work on the second one? On the first one, do you know what $S_n$ is and what it does to sets of $n$ things?

Comment: Yes I added my work, but I do not feel great about  the third exercise.

Comment: For the second one, you are overthinking. A group acting on itself is just group multiplication so $a$ is met by the group definition of what the identity does and $b$ is met because group multiplication is already associative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, id(x)=x and for permutations, we know that $g(h(x))=gh(x)$ so, its true.

Your proof for the second part is correct.

For the third part, consider $g\circ (h\circ x)=xhg\neq gh\circ x=xgh$ in general unless gh=hg

Answer (score 0):

For the last two questions, I don't think they are correct. For example, if the group multiplication is defined by $ g \circ x = g^{-1}x $, then $ g \circ h\circ x = g \circ (h^{-1}x) = g^{-1}h^{-1}x = (hg)^{-1}x = (hg)\circ x $, which is indeed a right action.

Comment: Indeed $g \circ x=g^-1 x$ is a right action. But, I don't quite understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Your third statement says that group G can not acts on itself by right multiplication, but the example above is indeed a right multiplication. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @user9516286, What you are saying is incorrect. The exercise states that the group action is defined by the group law itself, so the group action is given by $g \circ x = xg$. Your example is indeed a right action, but not the right multiplication defined by the group law